# Bolts/Bolts.h file not found - Facebook SDK already installed

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I am trying to integrate [Amazon Web SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) for iOS. I installed it manually (not using CocoPods) and in the documentation it says if you have the facebook SDK installed do not include `Bolts.framework` as this is included within Facebook SDK. However when doing so I get

```
"'Bolts/Bolts.h' file not found" in AWSNetworking.h file.
```

As stated in the Amazon SDK documentation if you include the Facebook SDK you do not need to add the Bolts framework. Do I need to change some of the code?

I am importing the SDK as standard using

```
#import <AWSiOSSDKv2/AWSCore.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you are using an older version of the Facebook SDK, which doesn't contain the Bolts framework. You can go ahead and import the `Bolts.framework`.

Comment: I am using Facebook SDK 3.20, the latest one. But did not get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was due to the use of Bolts in unit test. Xcode manages main project and unit test as separate targets, if your test bundle includes any class header file which imports Bolts/Bolts.h, then you will get this `'Bolts/Bolts.h' file not found` error. To fix it, you can delete and add Bolts framework to the project again but select both project target and test target.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using FacebookSDK(minimum of version 3.17.1 for ios) and still not getting the access the Bolts framework classes then add the whole Bolts SDK into your project from here: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS

Then go to your Project->Build Phases->Target Dependencies and add Bolts as a dependency. You would be able to use `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` after that.

Hope it helps.